# Manipulation + Frame.Navigate = crash

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have create [custom menu](https://github.com/programmersommer/WP8.1_Top_Slider_Menu) that is shown after swipe.
It could be moved with ManipulationDelta event with code like

```
    Canvas.SetTop(topmenu, Canvas.GetTop(topmenu) + e.Delta.Translation.Y);
```

Inside this menu there is a button and after clicking this button another page is loaded:

```
    private void btnSomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
    }
```

And here my application crashes. Seems that happend because of manipulation event.
I have tried to unsubscribe from manipulation events with

```
     private void btnSomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        topmenu.ManipulationDelta -= topmenu_ManipulationDelta;
        topmenu.ManipulationCompleted -= topmenu_ManipulationCompleted;
        topmenu.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.None;

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
    }
```

But without luck.

Currently only delay saves me:

```
        private async void btnSomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        topmenu.ManipulationDelta -= topmenu_ManipulationDelta;
        topmenu.ManipulationCompleted -= topmenu_ManipulationCompleted;
        topmenu.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.None;

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
    }
```

Is there is some smarter way?

Comment: Have you tried somehow to catch the exception and see what it's about? Have you subscribed to navigation events? Is *BlankPage1* a templated blank page without modifications (anything in constructor/variables that may cause in crash)? What happens with topmenu when you navigate (maybe here is the problem - for example trying to modify it, while it's no longer visible/present)?

Comment: Hi, @Romasz! This exception could not be catched with unhandledexception in App.xaml.cs. BlankPage1 is just page with nothing inside. Topmenu is not modified after clicking button.

Comment: I've downloaded your custom menu, added the click event, blank page, tried with navigation (without delay) and I can't reproduce the issue. I'm running W10 10586.420.

Comment: Thank you for trying on UWP. I'm getting exception on WP 8.1 (

Comment: On WP8.1 Device (Lumia 820) I also don't get exception.

Comment: Try to test with bowfinger (it has larger tapping area). Sometimes it's works but sometimes crashed. I have test on another phone (lumia 720) with same result

Comment: Weird, I tried few times more and it seems that in fact app sometimes closes without any notification. I'm not sure what can be the reason.